# Android DragLinearLayout dosn't work correctly and poor drag and drop, or barely drags images

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am using [this library](https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout)

I am adding ImageViews programatically, but the images can barely drag. it require very long press, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

this is the adding function

### Java

```
private ScrollView llCanvusContainer;
private DragLinearLayout llCanvus;
llCanvus = (DragLinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llCanvus);
llCanvusContainer = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.llCanvusContainer);
llCanvus.setContainerScrollView(llCanvusContainer);

private void appendImageToLinearLayout(DragLinearLayout layout,
                                           ParseFile parseFileImage,
                                           int w, int h,
                                           boolean fullWidth,
                                           boolean isPostImage,
                                           final int position)
            throws ParseException, IOException {

        ImageView imageView= new ImageView(this);
        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(

                ImageTools.
                        getBitmapFromUri(Uri.fromFile(
                                parseFileImage.getFile()),
                                this, fullWidth
                        )
        );

        // params
        //DragLinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParamsCenter =
                new DragLinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        w,
                        h);
        //viewParamsCenter.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.RIGHT;

        //imageView.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
        imageView.setId(position);
        imageView.setContentDescription(imageList.get(position).getObjectId());
        layout.addDragView(imageView, imageView);

        //layout.setViewDraggable(imageView, imageView);

        if(isPostImage){

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //showImageFullScreen(position);
                    Toast.makeText(EditPostActivity.this, "clicked " + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and here is how I add image views

```
        for (ParseObject imgObj : imageList) {

            // add the image to the linear layout
            appendImageToLinearLayout(
                    llCanvus,
                    imgObj.getParseFile("image"),
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    true,
                    true,
                    i
            );
```

## XML

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/llCanvusContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switchIsPublic">

    <com.jmedeisis.draglinearlayout.DragLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCanvus"
        style="@style/Gallery19crollbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switchIsPublic" />

</ScrollView>
```

The images show correctly, but the dragging doesn't work correctly.

## Edit

the drag and drop works fine when I remove the ScrollView.

Comment: Try putting into a FrameLayout instead of a ScrollView, or replace the Scrollview with the NestedScrollView and see if you have better luck. My guess is, you are dragging a view inside something that intercepts the drag events supported by the custom view.

Comment: @inner_class7 Thanks for the comment. The problem is that the setContainerScrollView(...) function accepts only ScrollView. and tried to cast it, but got an error.

Comment: Sounds like you are better off not using this library and rolling your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use recyclerView then linearlayout, you can happily use [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html).

I use ItemTouchHelper to reorder my list and it work nicely.

Here is the [blog post](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) I found